# Subclasses of abelian categories, that are closed under extensions and their complement as well and a construction of torsion pairs using them

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, torsion-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a length abelian category. A subclass $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ is called *super-closed* if $0\in \mathcal{S}$, $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under extensions and $\mathcal{A}\backslash\mathcal{S}$ is closed under extension. If $\mathcal{S}$ is super-closed, clearly

$\mathcal{S}^\top := \{M\in \mathcal{A}\mid M \cong 0\} \cup \mathcal{A}\backslash{\mathcal{S}}$

is super-closed. Now given a super-closed class $\mathcal{S}$ we can construct a torsion pair $(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{F})$ via

$\mathcal{T}:= \{M\in \mathcal{A}\mid \forall M'\subseteq M:M/M'\in \mathcal{S}\}$,

$\mathcal{F}:= \{N\in \mathcal{A}\mid \forall N'\subseteq N:N'\in \mathcal{S}^\top\}$.

One can show that every torsion pair can be obtained like this. Now we can do the same construction for $\mathcal{S}^\top$ and obtain a seccond torsion pair $(\mathcal{T}',\mathcal{F}')$. A natural question would be, what torsion pairs $(\mathcal{T}', \mathcal{F}')$ can accure if we fix $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$.

Is there any literature about super-closed classes and this construction of torsion pair?

Comment: Could you walk me a bit through your question please? You are fixing a torsion pair (T,F), for which there is 'a' super closed class S generating (T,F) as you describe. Is your question what sort of torsion pairs appear from the orthogonal classes of these classes S?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what i meant.

Comment: How do you show that every torsion pair can be obtained from a super-closed class? Given a torsion pair $\cal (T,F)$, how do you construct the desired $\cal S$?

Comment: We can chose $\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{T}$, so every torsion class is super-closed. In fact given $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ short exact with $L, N \notin \mathcal{T}$ we must have $M\notin \mathcal{T}$ since otherwise $N\in \mathcal{T}$ because $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under quotients. Similarly $\mathcal{F}$ is super-closed and we could chose $\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{F}^\top$.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, I guess, but TTF classes as described on Stenström's book are some of what you describe since in your notation (F, F') is one of the pairs you look for. Maybe its a good place to look

Comment: In the first sentence, I suspect there is a typo -- what is a "length abelian category"? Also, I think I need things spelled out for me -- what's an example of a super-closed class other than $\{0\}$ or $\mathcal A$?

Comment: A length abelian category is an albelian category with a length function. Equivalently, every infinite sequence of epimorphisms terminates, that is eventually it only consists of isomorphisms. Non trivial examples of of super-closed classes are torsion classes and torsion-free classes.